# ERROR: unsafe header/library path used in cross-compilation: '-I/usr/include

Tags: cross-compiling, configure, absolute-path, buildroot

vpp cross compilation while being integrated into buildroot project fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: unsafe header/library path used in cross-compilation: '-I/usr/include
```

it's appeared to have **oldincludedir** exporting for non-gnu toolchain enabled and so it producing this inclusion during configure process.

the problem seems to be quite common once the buildroot project added option for paranoid unsafe path checking as described [here](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2014-December/115097.html):

```
>> >> This error appear if one of the following paths is used during the
>> >> cross-compilation:
>> >> "/lib"
>> >> "/usr/include"
>> >> "/usr/lib"
>> >> "/usr/local/include"
>> >> "/usr/local/lib"
```

how to exclude **oldincludedir** generation inside configure or how to alter it's value instead of

```
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
```

to be configured similar to the **includedir** variable:

```
includedir='${prefix}/include'
```

?

Comment: for the quick update, the file responsible for the hardcoded path inclusion appeared to be: https://github.com/vpp-dev/vpp/blob/master/build-data/packages/vpp.mk where the unsafe path is hardcoded on the line 24

Answer (score 1):

detailed explanation about paranoid unsafe path checking being found [here](https://git.busybox.net/buildroot/commit/?id=5aa205eba4063ddf17a2e11420eea2a8aa7536a5) but the link seems to be very much temporary so the copy will be posted in this answer too:

**toolchain-external: instrument wrapper to warn about unsafe paths**

The CodeSourcery toolchains have a very interesting feature: they warn
the user when an unsafe header or library path is used, i.e a path
that will lead host headers or libraries to leak into the build.

This commit adds a similar functionality into our external toolchain
wrapper, so that it can be used with all external toolchains, and can
also be tuned as needed. By default, the external toolchain wrapper
now gives warnings such as:

```
  arm-linux-gcc: WARNING: unsafe header/library path used in cross-compilation: '-I /usr/foo'
  arm-linux-gcc: WARNING: unsafe header/library path used in cross-compilation: '-L /usr/bleh'
```

but the compilation continues successfully. One can then easily grep
in his build log to search for occurences of this message.

Optionally, if **BR_COMPILER_PARANOID_UNSAFE_PATH** is defined in the
environment to a non empty value, the external wrapper will instead
error out and abort the compilation.